# JavaFX Netbeans Error: no suitable method found

Tags: netbeans, javafx-2

I'm using Netbeans 7.2 and when I'm trying this [tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/get_started/form.htm) I'm getting this error :

[image]

the class code is as following :

```
public class Login extends Application {

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    GridPane grid = new GridPane();
    grid.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
    grid.setHgap(10);
    grid.setVgap(10);
    grid.setPadding(new Insets(25, 25, 25, 25));

    Text sceneTitle = new Text("Welcome");
    sceneTitle.setFont(Font.font("Tahoma", FontWeight.NORMAL, 20));
    grid.add(sceneTitle, 0, 0, 2, 1);

    Label userName = new Label("User Name:");
    grid.add(userName, 0, 1);

    Label pw = new Label("Password:");
    grid.add(pw, 0, 2);


    Scene scene = new Scene(grid, 300, 275);
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);

    primaryStage.setTitle("JavaFX Welcome");
    primaryStage.show();
}

/**
 * The main() method is ignored in correctly deployed JavaFX application.
 * main() serves only as fallback in case the application can not be
 * launched through deployment artifacts, e.g., in IDEs with limited FX
 * support. NetBeans ignores main().
 *
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}
}
```

I'm using JavaFX 2

any idea about this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your imports. It seems your `Label` is not `javafx.scene.control.Label`